# Issue in web.EnsureUser for FBA users programatically

Tags: sharepoint, claims-based-identity, fba

I am trying to ensure user through web.EnsureUser for FBA users. Here is my code snipplet. 
as an example :

```
string fbUsername = "i:0#.f|ie-fbamembership|userlogin";
SPUser userSP = site.RootWeb.EnsureUser(fbUsername);
```

But i get an error user does not exists. But i can surely add this user to the site collection manually.

But could not add the user through code (programatically).

Any ideas? i could not find a solution for this in the net.

- S.R.G
  SharePoint Developer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm very late to this question, but I had the same problem today and a colleague of mine finally found a solution.

I just use the `AllowUnsafeUpdates` property of my `SPWeb` object and write :

```
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
oUser = web.EnsureUser(userId);
```

In my case, `userId` is from a *PeoplePicker*, I construct it like this :

```
PickerEntity selectedEntity = (PickerEntity)peEditor.ResolvedEntities[i];
string userId = selectedEntity.Key;
```

Hope it can helps someone !